# Как остановить/уничтожить поток в Java

Tags: java, многопоточность

Как остановить/уничтожить поток по имени? Создается так:

```
Thread t = new Thread()...
```

С помощью `interrupt()` не получается, поток все равно продолжает работать. С помощью `stop()` останавливается поток, да больно не нравится мне использовать deprecated функции.

Comment: Прерывать потоки - это вообще плохая практика.

Answer (score 4):

1. Это возможно, только если вы что-то делаете в цикле и проверяете значение флага. Тогда можно выставить флаг этим методом.
2. Либо если какой-то сокет, ожидающий подключения, то его тоже можно закрыть.

За подробностями - [сюда](http://skipy.ru/technics/synchronization.html).